# I've been running three times a week

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

I read this conversation in an English textbook. I don't think the italicized part is correct. I've had an impression that present perfect continuous can't go with times or frequency.

A: How have you been feeling recently?

B: Great! *I've been running three times a week*. And I haven't been drinking as much coffee since I stopped working at the coffee shop.

Comment: It's fine. That's what B has been doing recently (the continuous tells it has started recently, it's still ongoing, and it hasn't become a habit)

Comment: It has become a habit, that is why the continuous is used in the sentence. He's been running three times a week, has been doing it recently, it is a new habit.

Answer (score 4):

The continuous tense can be used when talking about an action that has become habitual.

We wouldn't say

> I've been drinking three cups of coffee this morning.

but we can say

> I've been drinking coffee mid-morning for several years.

Comment: Can you say *he's been visiting Sarah in the hospital many times*?

Comment: Sorry - when you said _can't go with times_, I thought you meant _can't be used when a period of time is mentioned_ (a week). We can say "He's been visiting Sarah in hospital several times a week" or "frequently", but if we're talking about the total number of visits during her stay, it would be "has visited".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I should've said "number of times".

Comment: So, several times is different from several times a week.

Comment: Several times a week implies that over a number of weeks you did it several times each week. Several times just means you have done it at some point more than once.